# Should I test the created data after using Post Https Requests from Postman?

Tags: rest-api, api, postman

We are gonna use Postman to tests our API resources.

When you create a Post HTTP request to your API, it returns success response and not sure if the data were created successfully and correctly.

**Is it a good approach to trigger another HTTP requests to check if the data are in the database?** Say, you request the URI resource of the created data after you've just created it through Postman API Post Request and asserts the values. I want to know how you usually handle this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Practically saying when you do end to end testing, we have to validate database after POST operation(NOT always) to make sure that the ORM layer works fine.

If the question is YES or NO, then I would say YES, but don't over-crowd your test code with lot of DB connections and queries. Just be wise with when you want to verify the DB.